# Get physical address of struct dma_buf *dbuf

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver

I create a dma_buf* dbuf, how can I get the physical address for that buffer?
I need that to pass to HW register.

Thank you.

Comment: There are several examples of how 'struct dma_buf' are used in the Linux kernel.  Take a look at this one: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpu/drm/exynos/exynos_drm_dmabuf.c#L193 They attach it to a scatter-gather list.

Comment: Are u saying 'buffer->dma_addr = sg_dma_address(sgl);', this is my physical address? Thanks.

Comment: It is something like that.  I'd say try it and see what physical address you get.  Also look in the kernel source for a device similar to the one you are coding for and see how they manage DMA physical addresses.